# Multiselect showing dropdown values in dom but not displayed at web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multi-select

I am trying to show the dropdown with checkbox for multiselect, inorder to achive this I used multiselect jquery plugin

> html

```
<select class="searchfield" multiple="multiple" id="s0-billingStatus"/>
```

> js

```
$('#s0-billingStatus').multiselect({
                            columns: 1,
                            onLoad: billingStatus(id);
                        });

function billingStatus(id){
    **<<AJAX CALL and resultContent is having data >>**

           resultContent.billingStatusList.forEach(function(billing) {
             $("#s0-billingStatus").append('<option value="' + billing.billingStatusValue + '">' + billing.billingStatus + '</option>');
        });

         $("#s0-billingStatus").multiselect('rebuild');
}
```

I can see the option is filled in dom element, but ms-options and ms-list is empty and because of the options is not populating

[image]

I expected to have checkbox and option to be shown in dropdown
like below image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,Posting solution here in case anyone need,we
have to call multiselect only after ajax call complete.

```
$('#s0-billingStatus').multiselect({
                columns: 1
            });
```